# Max rectangle size inside another rectangle

Tags: math, language-agnostic, pseudocode

If I have a set of rectangles which can be any number.Rectangles have same size,and they are to fill a container (rectangle) of an given size.How do I work out the maximum size of the rectangles without having any of them overlap.

So if I have 3 rectangles which aspect ratio is 2.0 and the container is 3 * 2 then the max rectangle size is 2 * 1.

How can I do this programatically without hogging the processor by going through every possible combination.

float get_max_size(float width,float height,int num,float scale)

Comment: What language are you hoping to do this in?

Comment: Given the answer to your example, I'm guessing rotation is not allowed? If it were, you could fit at least 4 in that area.

Comment: to Abe Miessler:using C language,thanks

Comment: to Patrick87,it's a mistake,i have edited the question,the area size is 3*2

Comment: I am guessing you are looking for rectangle with integer dimensions, otherwise a rectangle with size 3 * 1.5 could easily fit in a 3 * 3 rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Search for [identical rectangles packing problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=identical+rectangles+packing+problem). It is a hard problem with no best solution. You must look for a heuristic that gives satisfactory results for your particular application.